# Row_Number based on two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I am looking to try to create the row number below, I have tried so many options but none seem to work. I would appreciate help.

I want the row order to look at sub_id and for each one do a sequential number, 1, 2, 3... I then want it to look at disc, and if that changes, go back to 1 again. I have tried concatenating them and using a key, but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
ID  sub_id  disc    ROW_NUMBER
1     1      OT       1
1     1      OT       2
1     1      OT       3
1     2      DT       1
1     2      DT       2
1     3      SL       1
1     3      SL       2
1     4      PH       1
1     4      PH       2
1     4      OT       1
1     5      OT       1
1     5      PH       2
1     5      DT       1
1     6      DT       1
1     6      DT       2
1     6      DT       3
1     7      SL       1
1     7      SL       2
1     7      DT       1
1     8      SL       1
1     8      SL       2
1     8      SL       3
1     9      DT       1
1     9      DT       2
1     9      DT       3
1     10     PH       1
1     10     DT       1
1     10     DT       2
1     11     OT       1
1     11     OT       2
1     11     OT       3
1     12     OT       1
1     12     OT       2
1     12     OT       3
```

Update
row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY sub_id ORDER BY disc) does not work. The ordering goes wrong when sub_id changes to 2. at this point it needs to revert back to 1, but it is 2.

Comment: *"I have tried so many options but none seem to work"* What were those attempts, you've omitted them from your question? YOu've also tagged 2 completely different RDBMS, what are you *really* using, MySQL or SQL Server? I have removed the conflicting tags. Please re-tag the product you are actually using.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want:

```
row_number() over (partition by id, sub_id, disc order by id)
```

Note:  You do not have a column that specifies the ordering of the columns -- or even uniquely identifies each row.  Hence, this just uses `order by id`.  You might want to include some other column there.

Comment: In the dataset there is no specific order, so I have ordered by ID, sub ID, disc in that order. This doesn't work, I have tried before. See comment below.

Comment: @BeckyPurland . . . Please show how this doesn't work in a db/sql fiddle.  It seems to do exactly what you want.

Comment: I don't know what a db/sql fiddle is. I put the code in exactly as posted and the answer is not as in my question. It goes 1,2,3,2,3,1,3. This isn't doing what I need. I tried concatenating sub_id and disc, then using row_number() over (partition by key order by key) and I get the same answer.

Comment: @BeckyPurland . . . At least edit the question and put the table creation and insert statements there so the data can readily be replicated.

Comment: The data is already in a table, I am querying the table so I do not need to create the table and insert the data. I am just trying to create a row_number or rank statement to do what I need it to do, but it seems this is an impossible task.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID , sub_ID , disc , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sub_ID ORDER BY disc)   from your table
```

Comment: How does this differ from Gordon's answer?

Comment: I tried this already, but it doesn't work. When the Sub ID changes to 2, the row number changes to 2, not back to 1.

Comment: when I use the same data ( ID , sub_ID , Disc)  I get the Row_Number like you wanted
I inserted the data to a table and I get the same result like you posted in the question
the difference from Larnu 's Answer :
we wrote it at the same time - he posted before me , I filled all the columns like the question required . 
I am using SQL 2012